# Bokeh initializing error

Tags: plot, bokeh

I'm trying to do clustering and plot with bokeh , I'm new in Bokeh , there is a warning message . this is my code :

```
#Clustering 
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from sklearn import cluster, datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
# define some helper functions

# set up initial data
n_samples = len(data)
n_clusters = 2
algorithm = 'MiniBatchKMeans'
X=data

#clustering with  k-means 
def clustering(X,  n_clusters):
    # normalize dataset for easier parameter selection
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)


# Generate the new colors:
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    model.fit(X)

    if hasattr(model, 'labels_'):
            y_pred = model.labels_.astype(np.int)
    else:
            y_pred = model.predict(X)
    return X, y_pred


#setup initials
y=n_clusters
X, y_pred = clustering(X,n_clusters)
spectral=np.hstack([Spectral6]*20)
colors=[spectral[i] for i in range(y)]

#plotting 
plot=figure(toolbar_location=None,title=algorithm)
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X[:,0],y=X[:,1],colors=colors))
plot.circle('x','y',fill_color='colors',line_color=None,source=source)

# set up widgets
Class=[
        'Comm',
        'Cr',
        'Ey',
         'F ',
        'Int ',
]

a_select = Select(value='Comm',
                          title='Select Class:',
                          width=200,
                          options=Class)
# min_Not = Slider(title="min_not ", start=0.000000e+00, end=1.876726e+13, value=0.000000e+00, step=1)
# max_Not = Slider(title="max_not", start=0.000000e+00, end=1.876726e+13, value=1.876726e+13, step=1)


Not_slider = Slider(title="Number of samples",
                        value=1500.0,
                        start=0.000000e+00,
                        end=1.876726e+13,
                        step=1,
                        width=400)

clusters_slider = Slider(title="Number of clusters",
                         value=2.0,
                         start=2.0,
                         end=10.0,
                         step=1,
                         width=400)

# set up callbacks
# def update_algorithm_or_clusters(attrname, old, new):
#     global X

#     algorithm = a_select.value
#     n_clusters = int(clusters_slider.value)

#     X, y_pred = clustering(X, n_clusters)
#     colors = [spectral[i] for i in range(y_pred)

#     source.data= dict(colors=colors, x=X[:, 0], y=X[:, 1])

#     plot.title.text = algorithm

# set up layout
selects = row(a_select, width=200)
inputs = column(selects, widgetbox(Not_slider, clusters_slider))

# add to document
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot))
curdoc().title = "Clustering"
```

and this is warning message , how could solve the problem ?

BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length
  lambda: warnings.warn("ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length", BokehUserWarning))

Comment: What does X look like at this line? `source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X[:,0],y=X[:,1],colors=colors))`

Comment: X is a matrix (234 rows and 6 columns), X is my data.

Comment: I want to make clustring using K-means of sklearn and show the plot using  Bokeh .the first column should be in x-axis and the 5 column should be as y-axis .

Comment: X is update after the call to the cluster function. Does it keep the same 234x6 dimension?

Comment: yes , it should be always same dimension.